# How to attach an .MDF file in a host directory data volume from within Docker mssql-server-linux container?

Tags: sql-server, linux, docker, windows-10, containers

I am mounting a host directory as a data volume with the following:

```
docker run -v c:\volumes:/var/opt/mssql/data2 
           -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" 
           -e "SA_PASSWORD=QWEqwe1!" 
           -e 'MSSQL_PID=Express'
           -p 1433:1433 
           -d microsoft/mssql-server-linux:latest
```

I created the volume with the instructions in the configuration topic here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-configure-docker#persist.

My host directory contains an .mdf file and an empty .ldf file. When attempting to attach the .mdf file using the following TSQL:

```
USE [master]
GO
CREATE DATABASE [MY_DATABASE] ON 
( FILENAME = N'/var/opt/mssql/data2/MY_DATABASE.mdf' ),
( FILENAME = N'/var/opt/mssql/data2/MY_DATABASE_log.ldf' )
FOR ATTACH
GO
```

I receive the following ERROR:

> "Error: 824, Severity: 24, State: 6.
>
> 2018-04-19 19:37:31.29 spid57      SQL Server detected a logical consistency-based I/O error: Insufficient bytes transferred. Common causes are backup configuration, insufficient disk space, or other problems with the storage subsystem such as corruption or hardware failure. Check errorlogs/application-logs for detailed messages and correct error conditions.. It occurred during a read of page (0:0) in database ID 0 at offset 0000000000000000 in file 'C:\var\opt\mssql\data\SS18SV_CORE_log.ldf'.  Additional messages in the SQL Server error log or operating system error log may provide more detail. This is a severe error condition that threatens database integrity and must be corrected immediately. Complete a full database consistency check (DBCC CHECKDB). This error can be caused by many factors; for more information, see SQL Server Books Online."

The error.log contains:

> "ERROR 5105  A file activation error occurred. The physical file name '\var\opt\mssql\data2\SS18SV_CORE.mdf' may be incorrect. Diagnose and correct additional errors, and retry the operation.
>
> 2018-04-19 19:00:14.79 spid54   Error: 824, Severity: 24, State: 6."

Any ideas how I can attach the .mdf file and .ldf file from my data volume successfully?

I am using Docker Community Edition Version 18.03.0-ce-win59 (16762) for Windows. My OS is Windows 10 Enterprise.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.